# relating template tag to dictionary in views.py in Django

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary, tags

I'm building a resources page, and I'm partitioning it among three available languages.

For each language, there will be a set of tags, and for each tag there will be a set of links for a certain item.

For instance:

```
English:
    Books:
      * The lord of the rings
      * The Silmarillion
      * Introduction to Calculus
      * Electricity for dummies
    Articles:
      * Why Python is superb (or something)
      * The Tao of Eating Too Much Sugar (or something)
Portuguese:
    Articles:
      * Investindo em títulos de Tesouro
```

And so forth and so on. You may notice that under "Portuguese" there isn't a Books tag. And that's the behavior I want: If the number of links which have a relationship with that specific tag is not greater than 0, then the tag should not show up.

That said, this is my models.py:

```
# tags
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"Esta tag já existe."}) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# link instances
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("link_detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

And a snippet from my resources_list.html:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<div style="display:inline;" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

  <span></span>
  <h3>{{tag.title}}</h3>
{% for link in links %}
    {% if link.tag == tag %}
    <a class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10" style="margin-top 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; float: left;" href="{{link.url}}"><p>{{link.title|truncatechars_html:36|safe}}</p></a>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1" style="float: right;" href="{% url 'link_detail' pk=link.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Up until now, I've managed to display all tags and related links, but the problem is, tags without content are still being shown.

I have written my views.py related function as follows:

```
def link_list_view(request):

    links = Link.objects.all().order_by('title')
    tags = Tag.objects.all().order_by('title')

    tag_dict = {}

    for tag in tags:
        tag_rel = tags.get(title=tag)
        tag_rel_entities = tag_rel.link_set.all()
        tag_rel_entities_number = len(tag_rel_entities)
        tag_dict[tag.title] = tag_rel_entities_number         

    return render(request, 'resources/resources_list.html', {'links':links, 'tags': tags})
```

Having removed irrelevant parts from my code. As you can see, I have managed to populate a dictionary with tag names and their number of relationships. If there are three links with the "Books" tag, then the dictionary will say: `"Books": 3`.

What I have thought might be the possible solution is the following logic:

```
For tag in tags
  If links_with_relation_to_tag_number >= 1
     <h3>{{tag.title}}</h3>
  Endif
  For link in links:
    if link.tag == tag
    ...
```

And I think a dictionary might be a good way of relating the tag with the template tag, and verify if the number of link relations to that tag is greater than zero, but I don't know how to proceed from now on.

I thank you in advance for your help. If any other detail or correction is required, just let me know and I'll insert it here.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your models, based on the following relationships.
Multiple languages -> each language can have 1 to n tags -> each tag can have 0 - n links

```
#languages
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# tags
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False) 
    language = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=False, blank=False, related_name="tags")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# link 
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name="links")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("link_detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

View

```
def link_list_view(request):
    languages = Language.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'resources/resources_list.html', {'languages':languages})
```

template

```
{% for language in languages %}
    {% with language.tags.all as tags %}
    {% for tag in tags %}
        {% with tag.links as links %}
        {% if link.count > 0 %}       
            <div style="display:inline;" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <span></span>
            <h3>{{tag.title}}</h3>
            {% for link in links %}
                <a class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10" style="margin-top 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; float: left;" href="{{link.url}}"><p>{{link.title|truncatechars_html:36|safe}}</p></a>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}   
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

if language is not your concern, then pass 'tags' from the view instead of languages (and remove the languages loop from the template). But based on your requirement ideally you should have looped by languages.